# Sharepoint double authentication wcf

Tags: wcf, security, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Environment :

- Sharepoint Foundation hosted at http://subdomain.mydomain.com
- WCF service hosted at http://anothersubdomain.mydomain.com

When I go to my sharepoint site, I'm being asked for my windows credentials. This is normal, I enter them and I can access the site.

Now, if I navigate to my WCF service, I have to enter my windows credentials again to have access to the service.

Is this something that can be fixed so I have some kind of a "single sign-on" between my 2 sites?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using Windows Authentication, I would highly recommend you use Kerberos. You would eliminate the need to enter credentials in either location.